Can I modify this Firebase template for my own notification?
When registering through Firebase, an email is sent to the email for confirmation. When clicking on the link, a window with a ready-made template opens:
image here, click me
Can this template be modified, for example, to round the edges, change the text, and so on?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Can I modify this Firebase template for my own notification?

No, there is no way you can customize the template or the text message. That's a standard template/text that is used when an email address is verified. However, you can create your own page and use for example, Firebase Hosting to host it. So to solve this, please see the official documentation for how to create custom email action handlers.

Hey Harry. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
